# How to organise an output file in perl?

Tags: perl

I made a piece of code in perl. I got the results I wanted, however, I would like my output to be formatted in the order of DATA.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use List::Util 'any';

my $input_file = 'DATA.csv';
my (@headers, %docs);

open my $fh, '>',"fh.txt";

open(my $Fhresult, '<', $input_file);
while (<$Fhresult> ) {
    last if (/^\d+\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s*$/);
}
while (<$Fhresult> ) {
    if ($. == 2) {
        chomp;
        s/^default,\s*//;
        @headers = split ( /[ ,. ;:\(\)\/\*\"]+/ );  
        next;
    }
    next unless /\S/;
    chomp;
    my ($file, @fields) = split /\s*,\s*|\s+/;
    $docs{$file} = [@fields] if any { $_ eq 'fault' } @fields;
    # ou bien? $docs{$file} = [@fields]; si on veut tout
}
close($Fhresult);

foreach my $doc (keys %docs) {
    print  "$doc:\n";
    foreach (0..$#headers) {
        printf ("%18s : %s\n", $headers[$_], $docs{$doc}->[$_]);
    }
    print  "\n";
}
```

_______________________DATA__________________________________________

```
20150627 19:08:00
default, primary, secondary, copy_direct, forced_copy, always_allow, type_of_dump, full_memory,
d100spupt, /dev/lg_du, /dev/sysdu, /var/adm, 1, 1, fault, disallow,
doc10, 5, fault, 7, ad8, 9, wu, disallow,
doc11, 5, fault, 5g7, 8, te, 10, disallow,
doc12, 5, fault, 7, ca, 9hg, 10, disallow,
doc13, 5, fault, 7, 8, 35hg, 10, disallow,
```

Output files:

file1:

```
d100spupt:
               primary : /dev/lg_du
             secondary : /dev/sysdu
           copy_direct : /var/adm
           forced_copy : 1
          always_allow : 1
          type_of_dump : fault
           full_memory : disallow
```

file2:

```
doc10:
               primary : 5
             secondary : fault
           copy_direct : 7
           forced_copy : ad8
          always_allow : 9
          type_of_dump : wu
           full_memory : disallow
```

file3

```
doc11:
                   primary : 5
                 secondary : fault
               copy_direct : 5g7
               forced_copy : 8
              always_allow : te
              type_of_dump : 10
               full_memory : disallow
```

- .
- .
- .

file5:

```
doc13:
                       primary : 5
                     secondary : fault
                   copy_direct : 7
                   forced_copy : 8
                  always_allow : 35hg
                  type_of_dump : 10
                   full_memory : disallow
```

Comment: If you are writing one file per line, you could just open/write/close a file for each line of your data.csv instead of storing the info in %docs and creating the files later.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand what they mean.
If you look at the DATA,
first line is the date and time,
second row Begin with "default" at
then start the processing of DATA
I would like that it makes each line in a file storage and of a file.
so I know file1 belongs to Line 1, Line 2 belongs to file2, etc.

Comment: Add a variable that you increment for each file, and use it to name the output file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hashes are not ordered, so when you loop in them with a `foreach`, the order of items is unpredictable.

To preserve the order you need a workaround. For example, you could append each keys of the hash in a list when you build it. Or you can use the [`Tie::IxHash`](http://search.cpan.org/~chorny/Tie-IxHash-1.23/lib/Tie/IxHash.pm) module.

However the fact you are facing this kind of situation reveals a conception problem and the only conclusion seems to be that the hash is not appropriate here.

An example with an array of hashes:

```perl
my @headers;
my @docs;

...

    my ($file, @fields) = split /\s*,\s*|\s+/;
    push @docs, {'file'=>$file, 'fields'=>\@fields} if any { $_ eq 'fault' } @fields;
}

close($Fhresult);

foreach my $doc (@docs) {
    print  $doc->{'file'} , ":\n";
    foreach (0..$#headers) {
        printf ("%18s : %s\n", $headers[$_], $doc->{'fields'}[$_]);
    }
    print  "\n";
}
```